# Django slice a single field in a queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, slice

I am trying to grab the first five characters from a char field but for only one field in a queryset but I keep getting various errors. Is there an effective way to do this in the view?

Code I am trying:

```
var = Model.objects.values('field1', 'field2'[:5], 'field3')
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can annotate the queryset with first 5 letters of `field2` using [`Substr`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#substr) function:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Substr 
queryset = Model.objects.all() 
queryset = queryset.annotate(field2_5=Substr('field2', 1, 5))
```

And, then use the annotated field `field2_5` in values:

```
values = queryset.values('field1', 'field2_5', 'field3')
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. But you have an extra curly bracket after the 5)

Comment: Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: Substr is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!