# slice a query result string field in annotation using Django 1.11

Tags: python, django, substr, annotate

I am trying to slice the last two characters of a field and annotate it to query result, using the method given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41105294/django-slice-a-single-field-in-a-queryset). Something like:

```
Person.objects.all()\
.annotate(
    code = Substr('Number', 1, -2),
)
```

The above code returns an empty string as soon as I use negative values as the third argument.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Since the question asks for the last two character (as we use negative index for python arrays), this is not a duplicate question at all. @schwobaseggl

Comment: The answer could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48017719/concatenation-of-a-field-related-to-multiple-rows-of-a-record-in-query-set-in-dj).