# How to use StringAgg aggregation functions in PostgreSQL 9.6 using DjangoORM

Tags: python, django, postgresql, concatenation, aggregate-functions

I am trying to join a field over a group. I could handle it in MySQL as described in [one of my previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48017719/concatenation-of-a-field-related-to-multiple-rows-of-a-record-in-query-set-in-dj). However I migrated to PostgreSQL now and the proposed solutions does not work in PostgreSQL 9.6.
According to [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#stringagg), it is possible to use StringAgg as described [here](https://gist.github.com/hellpanderrr/07a54cf8948b1a7f2f2f) or [here](http://harkablog.com/inside-the-django-orm-aggregates.html).
I believe, in newer versions of PostgreSQL I cannot execute the line:

```
from django.db.models.sql.aggregates import Aggregate as SQLAggregate
```

Which throws the error:

```
from django.db.models.sql.aggregates import Aggregate as SQLAggregate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.db.models.sql.aggregates'
```

How can I create my own Aggregate Function using [StringAgg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)?

#### Update

It seems I dodn't need to modify StringAgg to calculate what I needed.
I just imported it as Exprator described in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48353571/3993575):

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import StringAgg
```

and used it along with values() to group by the query. Since the fields were not string I had to use Cast as well:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import StringAgg
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models import TextField

query.annotate(
        AggregatedType = StringAgg(Cast('Types', TextField()),delimiter=',')
    )
```

Comment: Do you try the exists string_agg of PostgreSQL? The document is here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html

Comment: of course, that's what I have in mind. @MabuKloesen

Comment: Read: https://learnbatta.com/blog/usage-of-group_by-string_agg-in-django-postgresql-74/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import StringAgg
```

this is how you can import the aggregate functions

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I successfully imported StringAgg. Now I'm on creating custom aggregation function task.

Comment: the final answer could be found in the update of the question.

Comment: is there any way to replicate the functioning of StringAgg on MariaDB ?