# slice a query result string field in annotation using Substr and negative values

Tags: python, django, substr, annotate

I am trying to slice the last two characters of a field and annotate it to query result, using the method given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41105294/django-slice-a-single-field-in-a-queryset). Something like:

```
Person.objects.all()\
.annotate(
    code = Substr('str', 1, -2),
)
```

The above code returns an empty string as soon as I use negative values as the third argument. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to annotate a field for a positive index at first. Then you can use the Substr as follows:

```
Person.objects.annotate(
    PositiveIndex=ExpressionWrapper(Length('str') - 1, output_field=CharField()),
    code=Substr('str', F('PositiveIndex'))
).values('code')
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, however no ExpressionWrapper was needed since both length and -1 are integer. @Ahmad

 By the way, for those who want to implement, it should be done in two separate annotations.