# How to take slice of string when serializing a field (Django/DRF)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

First time asking here, I'll try to sound smart!
So, I've got a model called 'Article', and I've populated its 'text' field with 1000+ chars of text. How can I make it so I only send the first 200 chars of the 'text' field when I send an 'Article' serialized object through an endpoint?

views.py

```
class ArticleScrape(generics.ListAPIView):                                                                                                                                                                          
    queryset = Article.objects.all()                                                                                                                                                                                
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer                                                                                                                                                                            

    def list(self,request):                                                                                                                                                                           
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(queryset, many=True)                                                                                                                                                         
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):                                                                                                                                                               
    authors = EachAuthorSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)                                                                                                                                                        
    tags = EachTagSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)                                                                                                                                                              
    text = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)                                                                                                                                                                    
    class Meta:                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        model = Article                                                                                                                                                                                             
        exclude=('id',)
```

Do I need to perform this operation in the queryset? in the serializer? Do I annotate a field? I've tried many of this with no succes. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to return only the first 200 characters of the `text` field in your API response?

Comment: Exactly! That's what I wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different approaches, the first one that I prefer is to add a property to your model and add its field to the serializer:

```
class Article(models.Modle):
    ...
    @property
    def summary(self):
        return self.text[:200]


class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):                                                                                                                                                               
    summary = serializers.CharField()
```

and for the second approach you can use SerializerMethodField:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):                                                                                                                                                               
    summary = serializers.SerializerMethodField() 

    def get_summary(self, obj):
        return obj.text[:200]
```

Comment: That's pretty clean. I ended up doing it using a mix of two other SO answers:
[annotating a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920853/aggregate-and-other-annotated-fields-in-django-rest-framework-serializers), [getting a substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41105294/django-slice-a-single-field-in-a-queryset). For me it has been hard to assimilate all of the ways you can do the same thing in Django. It's nice to have options, but it's so overwhelming....

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be creating your own custom field:

```
class CustomCharField(serializers.CharField):

    def __init__(self, repr_length, **kwargs):
        self.repr_length = repr_length
        super(CustomCharField, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return super(CustomCharField, self).to_representation(value)[:self.repr_length]
```

And use it in serializers:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    text = CustomCharField(repr_length=200)
```

Comment: I see, that seems smart, and doesn't invove the database at all

Answer (score 1):

I like the 'CustomCharField' approach suggested by zeynel.  This version uses Django's [Truncator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/_modules/django/utils/text/).

```py
from django.utils.text import Truncator
from rest_framework import serializers

class TruncatedCharField(serializers.CharField):
    def __init__(self, length=200, **kwargs):
        self.length = length
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def to_representation(self, value):
        repr_ = super().to_representation(value)
        return Truncator(repr_).chars(self.length)
```